# Blank screen shown in the browser in the context of Cordova after restoring files

Tags: cordova, browser, gruntjs, npm, bower

I took over a **working** project built with Cordova, Ionic and AngularJS.

Unfortunately I had to restore the original files from scratch as the hard disk crashed.

So I ran as before:

```
 1. npm install -g cordova ionic bower grunt-cli
 2. npm install -g ios-sim ios-deploy
 3. npm install
 4. bower install
 5. grunt build
 6. ionic state reset
```

and finally `grunt serve`.

All went well and I could request http://localhost:8100/#/ as before without any problems so far.

However the page(s) I received is (are) blank (no 404) in either browser, neither using `/index.html` or so changed things.

Notes:

- 1: Previously I ran all the steps before with success.
- 2: Debugging in Chrome Canary did not provide a clue, port 8100 is definic in Ionic settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing the entire system one more time helped!